# Clipping tif with polygon in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff, clip

I'm trying to clip a .tif (Ordnance Survey download file) with a parish boundary polygon, but ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.1 won't let me drop the .tif into the Input Features box: and gives me this error message:

> One or more dropped items were invalid and will not be added to the control.

With no explanation of how the file is invalid. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Is the .tif georeferenced? I mean, is it just a tif or does it have any gis information with it?

Comment: It was a data download from Ordnance Survey and has British National Grid projection in my map document. If I check its properties, what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong Clip tool. There are two, one for clipping vectors and one for rasters. You want the one in the "Raster Processing" toolbox:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "Extract by Mask' tool as well as the Clip tool within the Raster Processing toolbox.

[image]

The result when I ran the tool looked like this:

[image]